# Force the order of the legend of plots from the same data frame overlaid in the same graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

As a new user, the first question I sent was accompanied with a non reproducible code. Here, I edited my question to have a reproducible example (the corresponding answer from Constantinos is at the end of this message):

***Question:*** I want to force the order (not the labels) of the legend of a graph combining 2 different plots (geom_line and geom_point) with different levels of the same factor.

```
x <- data.frame("ID" = 1:16, "Factor" = 
c("a","a","a","a","b","b","b","b","c","c","c","c","d","d","d","d"), 
        "Data" = runif(16))

d1 <- x %>% filter(Factor %in% c("a","b"))
d2 <- x %>% filter(Factor %in% c("c","d"))
d1$Factor <- factor(d1$Factor, levels = c("b","a"))
d22$Factor <- factor(d2$Factor, levels = c("d","c"))

ggplot () +  
  geom_line(data=d12, aes(x=ID, y=Data, colour = Factor),  size = 0.7) +
  geom_point(data=d12, aes(x=ID, y=Data, colour = Factor), size = 1.5)
```

In the plot I obtain, the order of the legend is alphabetical (a,b,c,d). How can I force the ordering of the legend such as it is: d,c,b,a?

---

The solution to the problem, given by Constantinos, was (I adapted the text from the original to match the new code):

```
ggplot(temp12, aes(x = ID, y = data, colour = Factor)) +
  geom_line(data = temp1,  size = 0.7) +
  geom_point(data = temp2,  size = 1.5) + 
  scale_color_discrete(breaks = c("d","c","b","a")
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to improvise as your question is not a reproducible example (see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)) but I think you are looking for the following:

```
ggplot(temp12, aes(x = Date, y = data, colour = Variable)) +
  geom_line(data = temp1,  size = 0.7) +
  geom_point(data = temp2,  size = 1.5) + 
  scale_color_discrete(breaks = c("WT.LH.4","WT.LH.13","WT.GE.2","WT.SP.13","WT.SP.8","WT.SP.4"))
```

**EDIT:**

Following your updated question, I'm attaching your code (with some corrections as indicated), and the result as requested.

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(1234)
x <- data.frame("ID" = 1:16, "Factor" = 
                  c("a","a","a","a","b","b","b","b","c","c","c","c","d","d","d","d"), 
                "Data" = runif(16))

d1 <- x %>% filter(Factor %in% c("a","b"))
d2 <- x %>% filter(Factor %in% c("c","d"))
d1$Factor <- factor(d1$Factor, levels = c("b","a"))
d2$Factor <- factor(d2$Factor, levels = c("d","c")) # Corrected d22 to d2

ggplot () +  
  geom_line(data = d1, aes(x=ID, y=Data, colour = Factor),  size = 0.7) + # Changed d12 to d1
  geom_point(data = d2, aes(x=ID, y=Data, colour = Factor), size = 1.5) + # Changed d12 to d2
  scale_color_discrete(breaks = c("d","c","b","a"))
```

[image: Reverse order legend]

This allows for a more general, manual ordering of the labels. If the reverse order is what was needed, you could also look up the `fct_rev` function from the `forcats` package.

Comment: Many thanks, Constantinos (sorry for the typos in my updated answer). Your help was much appreciated. Best wishes. Nicolas